# How do i import webdriver from selenium and beautifulsoup using jupyter notebook?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to import `Selenium and BeautifulSoup` liberaries although I have downloaded and installed them using `Anaconda Prompt` but still i'm not able to import webdriver and BeautifulSoup on jupyter notebook.

I've tried a link which guides to clinicalgraphics at Anaconda Cloud, but it says the user,clinicalgraphics is not available or something.
Also, i tried writing this code on Anaconda Prompt(AP) `conda install -c clinicalgraphics selenium` but didn't work.

on jupyter notebook:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

I expected downloading and installing selenium and BeautifulSoup through AP is all i have to do to import webdriver and BeautifulSoup libraries in jupyter notebook. But i get an error message instead quoting

```
'ModuleNotFoundError: no module name 'selenium'.
```

Comment: "I've tried a link which guides to clinicalgraphics at Anaconda Cloud" - add that link and explain what exactly you trying, welcome to SO, please read [mcve]

Comment: In the notebook, try `!pip install selenium` (with the exclamation mark).

Comment: @JackFleeting It worked.Thank you for the support 'cheers'.
But half of the question still remains, how to import BeautifulSoup lib ? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dev I have to import BeautifulSoup library on my jupyter notebook.
I have already installed it with Anaconda Prompt but i'm not able to import it when i write:
 `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`
on jupyter .ipynb file.

Comment: Try importing Beautifulsoup by using `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @JackFleeting it worked. TY once again.